# How to use Lambda to serve an S3-hosted React app through an ALB without cloudfront

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to use aws lambda and api gateway to serve static front-end files (js, css, html, etc) in S3. Ultimately this also needs to be passed to an Alb as well. On account of project restrictions I can’t use cloudfront. I’ve heard that nginx reverse proxy can be used instead. I’m unsure if that is even needed. I already have the apis deployed through the alb using fargate but i need the uis to be in s3. Is this possible and how would something like that be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue. First, I created an ALB with 443 and 80 listeners. Second, I attached a self-signed cert to the 443 listener and added two security groups, one that controlled access to the ALB and one that allowed inbound access from the ALB only. Third, I built an example React app and copied those files s3 (tested this locally before doing so on port 3000). Fourth, I created a lambda function with an env variable for the bucket location passed in which referenced the index.html file in s3 where the React files were stored. Last, I registered a lambda target group in the ALB that referenced the existing function mentioned above. Also had to give the lambda role access to s3 by attaching the relevant policy in IAM.